# Do the apoc.import use merge or create to add new data?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

```
CALL apoc.import.csv(
  [{fileName: 'file:/persons.csv', labels: ['Person']}],
  [{fileName: 'file:/knows.csv', type: 'KNOWS'}],
  {delimiter: '|', arrayDelimiter: ',', stringIds: false}
)
```

For this example, internally, does the 'import' use merge or create to add nodes, relationships and properties? I tested, it seems it uses 'create'  to add new rows even for a new ID record. Is there a way to control this? When to use apoc.load VS apoc.import?  It seems apoc.load is a lot more flexible, where users can choose to use cypher commands specifically for purposes. Right?

Comment: Are you getting duplicate nodes, relationships, or both?

Comment: I only tested nodes. So I am talking about nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[From the source of `CsvEntityLoader`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/16581f3253f82e75506428dfd2a498346c6bfb1d/core/src/main/java/apoc/export/csv/CsvEntityLoader.java#L101) (which seems to be doing the work under the covers), nodes are blindly created rather than being merged.

While there's an `ignoreDuplicateNodes` configuration property you can set, it just ignores IDs duplicated within the incoming CSV (i.e. it's not de-duplicating the incoming records against your existing graph). You could protect yourself from creating duplicate nodes by creating an appropriate [unique constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/constraints/#administration-constraints-unique-nodes) on any uniquely-identifying properties, which would at least prevent you accidentally running the same import twice.

Personally I'd only use `apoc.import.csv` to do a one-off bulk load of data into a fresh graph (or to load a dump from another graph that was exported as a CSV by something like `apoc.export.csv.*`). And even then, you've got the [batch import tool](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#batch-importer) that'll do that job with higher performance for large datasets.

I tend to use either [the built-in `LOAD CSV`](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#import-load-csv) command or `apoc.load.csv` for most things, as you can control exactly what you do with each record coming in from the file (such as performing a `MERGE` rather than a `CREATE`).

Comment: FYI: A request to have the `ignoreDuplicateNodes` option actually check for duplicates in the DB (instead of just in the file) was [brought up before](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1048), but nothing has been done yet to address it.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by by @Pablissimo's answer, the `ignoreDuplicateNodes` config option (when explicitly set to `true`) *does not actually check for duplicates in the DB* - it just checks within the file. A request to address this hole was [brought up before](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1048), but nothing has been done yet to address it. So, if this is a concern for your use case, then you should not use `apoc.import.csv`.

**The rest of this answer applies iff your files never specify nodes that already exist in your DB.**

If your node CSV file follows the `neo4j-admin import` command's [import file header format](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/file-header-format/) and has a header that specifies the `:ID` field for the column containing the node's unique ID, then the [apoc.import.csv](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/import/import-csv/) procedure should, by default, **fail** when it encounters duplicate node IDs (within the same file). That is because the procedure's `ignoreDuplicateNodes` config value defaults to `false` (you can specify `true` to skip duplicate IDs instead of failing).

However, since your node imports are not failing but are generating duplicate nodes, that implies your node CSV file does not specify the `:ID` field as appropriate. To fix this, you need to add the `:ID` field and call the procedure with the config option `ignoreDuplicateNodes:true`. Or, you can modify those CSV files somehow to remove duplicate rows.